# Delete query does not end

Tags: mysql, join, delete

I have a following table with 1 million records :

```
CREATE TABLE `activity` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subscription_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action` enum('init','confirm','suspend') DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `num` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float(5,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `num` (`num`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

I want to delete entries for same `num` value but that are old. So I came up with following query :

```
delete activity
 from activity
 inner join (
   select max(id) as maxid, num
     from activity
    group by num
   having count(*) > 1) duplic on duplic.num = activity.num
where activity.id < duplic.maxid;
```

The select query works fine, returns around 400.000 records. But if I try delete, the query executes infinitely. What might be wrong with this? How to investigate?

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to find out the execution plan. If your version does not support explaining of DELETE statements, just change it to SELECT * and use explain on that. Add the plan to your question.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: This Delete is not using a subquery, so it should not be related to the fact that MySQL can't Delete from a table using a Select from the same table in a subquery.

You don't need MAX to delete all but the latest row:

    `DELETE a1 
    FROM activity AS a1 
    JOIN activity AS a2 
      ON a1.num = a2.num 
     AND a1.id < a2.id;`

Comment: "Infinitely"? Maybe you're simply not waiting enough? What to SHOW PROCESSLIST and EXPLAIN say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:

1. Create temp table with num and max(id).  400K rows
2. Chunk that table to do only 1000 deletes at a time; there would be a JOIN in the DELETE to the temp table.

[*More on Chunking for DELETE*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Plan B:

You need to keep 60% of the table, correct?  So, it may be faster to rebuild the table with only the desired rows.

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE activity;
ALTER TABLE new ADD UNIQUE(num);   -- in order to catch dups
INSERT IGNORE   -- silently ignore dup nums
    INTO new SELECT * FROM activity
    ORDER BY num, id DESC;   -- same effect as MAX
RENAME TABLE activity TO old, new TO activity;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Plan C:

```
ALTER TABLE IGNORE activity
    DROP KEY num,
    ADD UNIQUE(num);
```

Problem (with Plan C): you cannot predict which of dup rows will be deleted.